# Application error at heroku first deployment

Tags: node.js, heroku, application-error

I am trying to deploy the react.js project on Heroku first time but I faced an Application error after my deployment
here are the complete Heroku logs which I got in CLI
but I can't figure it out kindly have a look at it and help me to fix it

````
2022-03-27T21:38:28.785305+00:00 app[web.1]: errno: -2,
2022-03-27T21:38:28.785305+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'ENOENT',
2022-03-27T21:38:28.785305+00:00 app[web.1]: syscall: 'spawn xdg-open',
2022-03-27T21:38:28.785306+00:00 app[web.1]: path: 'xdg-open',
2022-03-27T21:38:28.785306+00:00 app[web.1]: spawnargs: [ 'http://localhost:5473' ]
2022-03-27T21:38:28.785306+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2022-03-27T21:38:28.952616+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-03-27T21:38:29.035319+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2022-03-27T21:38:30.362490+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=prashantkr006-portfolio.herokuapp.com request_id=32017955-d828-4cb3-83bb-5549ef9b708d fwd="124.253.43.194" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-03-27T21:38:30.929163+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=prashantkr006-portfolio.herokuapp.com request_id=536688a3-05d6-4ae5-8e71-9a7416288a7c fwd="124.253.43.194" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-03-27T21:38:34.193164+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=prashantkr006-portfolio.herokuapp.com request_id=63109b08-cfb0-46c3-b456-49cfffcb4b2c fwd="124.253.43.194" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-03-27T21:38:34.734662+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=prashantkr006-portfolio.herokuapp.com request_id=f1db7ca5-c99c-4048-a461-ac45a649d965 fwd="124.253.43.194" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-03-27T21:38:36.322456+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=prashantkr006-portfolio.herokuapp.com request_id=1fe2ea64-25aa-4424-aa92-b314327af931 fwd="124.253.43.194" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-03-27T21:38:36.933721+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=prashantkr006-portfolio.herokuapp.com request_id=d5e392cd-1ccd-42b7-aa11-074c69da34b4 fwd="124.253.43.194" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-03-27T21:38:37.425993+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=prashantkr006-portfolio.herokuapp.com request_id=dbdd86bd-4a02-485e-9032-6df69426502a fwd="124.253.43.194" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-03-27T21:50:02.264561+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=prashantkr006-portfolio.herokuapp.com request_id=53022457-3a00-423f-ae40-37e33e685d23 fwd="124.253.43.194" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-03-27T21:50:02.898755+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=prashantkr006-portfolio.herokuapp.com request_id=536c5ee9-ec09-4360-8821-c8248db464a5 fwd="124.253.43.194" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-03-27T21:52:42.850643+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=prashantkr006-portfolio.herokuapp.com request_id=99a80e06-a2e5-4ae7-800a-a945e3c58ff2 fwd="124.253.43.194" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-03-27T21:52:43.403302+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=prashantkr006-portfolio.herokuapp.com request_id=c830cdd8-66ca-446b-a6cb-ad8308759ffe fwd="124.253.43.194" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https```
how to fix it?
````

Comment: Can u show ur index.js?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, your issue is similar to this one :
[have an error when deploy react app in heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67516491/have-an-error-when-deploy-react-app-in-heroku)

By the way, if this concerns a react.js app you should edit your post tags, you put node.js instead of react.js